# Different header on different pages of word doc file in powershell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word, powershell-2.0

i am creating a doc file after reading several text files and trying to add 
text file name in header of page corresponding in the **doc file** in **powershell**
but the code below write the last read file as header on each page.
note:- data is displayed corected on doc file only header is not written correctly.
How to write text file name as header on doc (means same doc will have different header on different pages)

```
$dir="D:\abcd"
$val=ls $dir
$file_count=(get-childitem .).count
$page_count=0
$hash=@{};
set-variable -name wdAlignPageNumberCenter -value 1 
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $true
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1)
$Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1)
$Footer = $Section.Footers.Item(1)
$Footer.PageNumbers.Add($wdAlignPageNumberCenter)
$selection=$word.Selection
$page="`tPage";
$loop=1
foreach ($file in $val){
    $filename = "D:\abcd\$file"
    $filedata = (get-content $filename);
    $Footer.Range.Text=$page
    $head="ABCD`t`tFile ID: $file"
    $Header.Range.Text = $head  
}
$savepath="D:\abcd\$file.docx"
$Doc.SaveAs([ref]$savepath) 
$Doc.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Word, you can create unique headers for different parts of the document by splitting it up by [section](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-section-break-HA010031073.aspx).  The problem you're experiencing is because there appears to be only one section, so there will also only be one header... which gets overwritten in the `foreach` loop.  This behavior is consistent with the result you describe, as it would then make sense that the last read file will appear as the header across the entire document.

You've already specified one section (and one set of headers/footers) here:

```
$Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1)
$Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1)
$Footer = $Section.Footers.Item(1)
```

Just modify your logic to create a new one each time you want a different header.

Comment: so does it mean that if each time when foreach loop start if i put section with corresponding filename in loop then it will work.?

Comment: Yeah give that a try, and make sure to remove the section logic outside of the loop so that you don't create a section you don't use.  Be aware of the loop's [scope](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx).

Comment: sorry i am new to powershell ...what do you mean by "remove the section logic outside of the loop" and how to do it

Comment: I just meant to remove the existing lines that I quoted above that reference $Section, and place them *inside* of the loop. Don't worry about the wording if it confused you, your initial comment makes it sound like you're on the right track.

Comment: i tried that one but it was not working ...... could you please put your code if you have tried it,that would be helpful